# core plot - reloatData and graph

Tags: core-plot, reload

I have an UIViewController(GraphViewController) with a custom UIView (PlotView) that contains a CPTXYGraph, in PlotView I have an NSMutableDictionary with all my equations, from GraphViewController I edit this dictionary and than I reload my graph with a [self.plotview.graph reloadData], the dictionary is reloaded but the graph not, if I pan or zoom the graph is reloaded...where is the problem?

I try to do a setNeedsDisplay  but nothing, any help?

Comment: What does "the dictionary is reloaded" mean? Is the plot requesting the new data from the datasource?

Comment: Mean that is not a problem of datasource, the dictionary is edit from the controller and when the plot ask for this value on the delegate I see the correct data!i think is a problem of view refresh

Comment: Are you using a Core Plot hosting view as a subview of your view (`PlotView`)? Does the graph appear not appear at all, or is the issue just updating the graph with new data?